# Mongodb join multiple collection and get text value from foreign key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have this MongoDB query, but it doesn't give me back text value instead of foreign key, query looks like this

```
db.getCollection('bol_rac').aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
        {
          from: "second_collection op",
          localField: "id_op",
          foreignField: "id_op",
          as: "op"
        }
},  

{
    $lookup:
        {
          from: "third_collection",
          localField: "id_bol",
          foreignField: "id_bol",
          as: "bl"
        }
},

{
    $match:{"id_op" : 70149}
 }

]);
```

and my second_collection looks like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59d2a0b36fb6056aeca4db93"),
"id_op" : 70149,
"naziv" : "Some-text-value"
```

and my third_collection looks like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59d2a0926fb6056aeca4db30"),
"id_bol" : 51,
"naziv" : "Some-text-value"
```

So, instead let's say 51 and 70149 as foreign key in main collection, i want to get back text values from second and third collections, is that possible in Mongo?

My result looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d2a0576fb6056aeca4d6e4"),
    "id" : 2,
    "id_p" : 1,
    "id_drz" : 688,
    "age" : 6,
    "id_op" : 70149,
    "id_os" : 1,
    "id_bol" : 51,
    "id_od" : 120
}
```

But i want to my result looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d2a0576fb6056aeca4d6e4"),
    "id" : 2,
    "id_p" : 1,
    "id_drz" : 688,
    "age" : 6,
    "id_op" : Some-text-value(instead of 70149),
    "id_os" : 1,
    "id_bol" : Some-text-value(instead of 51),
    "id_od" : 120
}
```

Comment: Yes.   Please post the result of your query with the 2 $lookups, describe your desired output, and we'll show how to pluck naziv and other items.

Comment: The value of id_op (Some-text-value) would be the value of field naziv from collection 2 and the value of id_bol would be the value of naziv from collection 3?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti yes, that is it what i am looking for, and i don't know how to edit existing query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you are trying to find all the material associated with `id_op` 70149.  So put the `$match` as the **first** operator in the pipeline, not the last.

Here's the complete query:

```
db.bol_rac.aggregate([
{$match:{"id_op" : 70149} },
{
    $lookup:    {
        from: "coll2",
        localField: "id_op",
        foreignField: "id_op",
        as: "op"
    }
},
{
    $lookup:    {
        from: "coll3",
        localField: "id_bol",
        foreignField: "id_bol",
        as: "bl"
    }
}

// Turn the $lookup arrays into a single object:
,{$addFields: {id_op: {$arrayElemAt: ["$op",0] },
               id_bol: {$arrayElemAt: ["$bl",0] }
    }}

// ... and grab naziv from within and assign it:
,{$addFields: {id_op: "$id_op.naziv", id_bol: "$id_bol.naziv"}}

// Drop the array (optional)
,{$project: {op:0, bl:0}}
                  ]);
```

Comment: I run this query and i get error message "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."

Comment: You must a typo in there somewhere.   That snippet above added to the tail of your original post yields your target output.

Comment: how can i send you snippet to see, because i don't get error message in code, but i get on execution error